# HardHat with gas-report reports not understandable

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

I'm using HardHat with [gas-report](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-gas-reporter) but I'm not able to understand the following results:

- `Optimizer enabled: false`
- `Runs: 200`
- `Block limit: 30000000 gas`
- `% of limit`

Here I have marked with red square the fields:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC7gO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Optimizer (whether it's enabled or disabled) and the target amount of contract runs, to which the optimizer should optimize the contract bytecode, are options of the Solidity compiler. When you compile the contract with an optimizer, it can decrease either the total bytecode size - or the amount of gas needed to execute some functions. ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/optimizer.html#optimizer-parameter-runs))

Block limit states the amount of gas units that can fit into one block. Different networks might have different values, some have dynamically adjusted limits, plus you can usually set your own limit if you're using an emulator or a private network. ([docs](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#block-size))

% of limit states a portion of how much your contract deployment took in the total block limit. Example from your table: Deployment of `HashContract` cost 611k gas units, which is approx. 2% of the 30M block limit. If the number exceeds 100%, the transaction would never be included in a block - at least not in a block with the same or smaller limit. Also, if the transaction has a low `gasPrice` and a high % of the total block limit, some miners/validators might not be able to fit the transaction into a block (as transactions are usually ordered from highest `gasPrice` to lowest), so it might take longer to be included in a block.